# Binding mode for IBM MQ with a JavaSE application on same server possible?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

Server OS: Linux
IBM Websphere MQ 8.0
Java 8



I am trying to create a java program that is on the same server as the IBM MQ. Trying to use binding mode and it's throwing me error.

```
2016-10-05 13:20:54 ERROR LogReader:181 - JMS ERROR: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8445)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7814)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6024)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:136)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:209)
    at com.timeinc.rde.mq.LogReader.run(LogReader.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$4: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8598: Failed to load the WebSphere MQ native JNI library: 'mqjbnd'.
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1268)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:259)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:221)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.<init>(LocalMQ.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.<init>(LocalServer.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:706)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:640)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8437)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1240)
    ... 21 more
```

I have set the environment variable using setmqenv. I was reading the JDNI set up but it seems like it's mostly for an application server(JavaEE) where it points to the mqjbnd library. All other tutor I ran across turn off security and connect via tcp.

Comment: [I found an old APAR on this topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ84448). Can you check if all the components here have the same bitness (32/64)?

Comment: A little bit different but I'll look into it. I am using version 8.0 MQ and that one is talking about 7.0 and 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd (A file or
directory in the path name does not exist.)
and mine is java.library.path
Which all the example that I saw got to do with a server and having the server point to that java library class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the MQ Java Native Interface (JNI) libraries that are required in order to establish BINDINGS transport mode connections are not available on the Java library path.  See here in the KC:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10340_.htm

So, try start your application with the Java system property:

-Djava.library.path=MQ_INSTALL_DIR/java/lib

for 32-bit JVMs or:

-Djava.library.path=MQ_INSTALL_DIR/java/lib64

if using a 64-bit JVM.

This will resolve the exception, "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path".

Comment: This is the issue for the error I am having. Funny thing is I found out yesterday as well. Now I run into another issue of needing a user name and password. I guess binding mode still need a user name and password?

Comment: You need to pass a username so the queue manager can check the user has sufficient authority to do the operations the application is trying; for example put a message to a queue or subscribe to a particular topic. A password maybe needed if using MQ connection authentication (CONNAUTH)